# Election cycle unmarred by ... (multiple choice questions) - Why are these options the answers?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

The multiple choice question below appeared in a test of mine. The answers given were (B, E, and G). I'm okay with the third choice, but having trouble with the first two. Can anyone explain why the answers to the first two blanks should be options B and E.

> In an election cycle unmarred by a spate of television advertisements in which one candidate drags the other through the mud, it is easy for voters on both sides of the political spectrum to think they have (i) __________, and perhaps partially explains why each is (ii) __________ a pronounced bias in news reporting. One newspaper will unleash a fusillade of incriminating articles on one candidate, while printing little that is (iii)____________ the other. A newspaper on the other side of the political spectrum will respond in kind. The overall effect, then, is not much different from the television advertisements: one candidate is the devil incarnate, the other a clear choice for national office.

i. (A) reached an impasse **(B) scored a moral victory** (C) been absolved of blame

ii. (D) similarly immune from  **(E) equally susceptible to** (F) likely complicit in

iii. **(G) averse to**  (H) approbatory of  (I) cognizant of

Comment: The first sentence hardly makes sense. If the election was "unmarred", why bring up the "spate of ... advertisements". **What** "partially explains why ..."?

Comment: @Photon The election was unmarred by negative ads. It may have been marred those wretched journalists dragging up all that muck that the ads didn’t.